# can you tell what is wrong with this? error occur " MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:" laravel 5.0.1

Tags: php

this is routing code .

Route::get('ok','SignUPControler@create');
    Route::post('stor',['middleware'=>'auth','SignUPControler@store']);

Answer (score 2):

submit form to store data must be like.

```
<form method = 'post' action = '/store'>
<input name = '_token' type = 'hidden' value = '{{Session::token()}}'>
.
.`
</form>`
```

but if you want to make something like Authentication using middlewars in laravel 
please check this out 
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication